# Statistical error for kernel density estimator

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, kernel-smoothing

First of all sorry to use the word "error" without additional specification.

I have a dataset with few elements ~(10-100) and I want to show them using a  KDE (instead of simple histogram, for example). I want to show the KDE with an error band, corresponding to the statistical error (exactly as for an histogram usually $\sqrt{N}$ or a Poissonian confidence interval for every bin are used).

Here what I am doing:

- Build the original KDE from the dataset (using this adaptive recipe http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0011057)
- Resample (bootstrap) $N$ times the original dataset and build $N$ different KDEs ($\{KDE_i\}_i^N$)
- For every point $x_0$ of the variable find the smallest $[y_{lo}(x_0), y_{hi}(x_0)]$ interval containing 68% of the $\{y_i(x_0)\}=\{KDE_i(x_0)\}_{i=1}^N$

The question is: is it a correct procedure? Are there other approaches, maybe more analytical?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. How did you manage to solve it in the end?

Comment: no, still using bootstrap